# javascript syntax error on import statement?

Tags: javascript, importerror

On trying to import library in a javascript file (.js), 
Syntax error is thrown,

```
import deepEqual from "deep-equal";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I am using nodejs to execute the file from command line.
to execute I use:

> node sample.js

Library installation update

```
npm version 6.11.3
node version 12.11.1
npm install deep-equal - completed
```

Comment: It's just as the error message says...?

Comment: Do you have a HTML file with a `<script type="module">`?

Comment: Where's that statement in your code?

Answer (score -1):

Mark your script as module type:

```
<script type="module">
  import deepequal from "deep-equal";
</script>
```

Comment: "*I am using nodejs*"